# Проблема вращения сцены OpenGL

Tags: математика, opengl, матрицы, opengles

Мне нужно вращать сцену вокруг `X` и `Y` осей. Проблема в том, что я не могу использовать команды

```
gl.glRotatef(deltaX, 0, 1, 0);
gl.glRotatef(deltaY, 1, 0, 0);
```

так как первый вызов модифицирует `X` ось, и она уже не будет равна `1, 0, 0`.
Я считаю новое значение для оси `X`, учитывая первое вращение:

```
gl.glRotatef(deltaX, 0, 1, 0);
gl.glRotatef(deltaY, Math.cos(deltaX), 0, -Math.sin(deltaX));
```

После этого, по идее, все должно работать как надо, но вращение производится все равно неверно. В чем здесь может быть ошибка?

Comment: 1. Вращения по осям *X* и *Y* — это повороты «вверх-вниз» и «влево-вправо»? 2. Возьмите самое первое (отвергнутое) решение и попробуйте поменять в нём строки местами.

Comment: @Arhad deltaX - проведение пальцем по горизонтали на экране, вращение вокруг оси Y, deltaY - проведение пальцем по вертикали, вращение вокруг оси X.

Comment: Скорее всего, в OpenGL трансформации применяются в порядке, обратном их заданию (в силу свойств матричного умножения). Вы всё-таки попробуйте `gl.glRotatef(deltaY, 1, 0, 0); gl.glRotatef(deltaX, 0, 1, 0);`.

Comment: @Arhad не, не получилось( такой же эффект, только инвертированный. Попробовал так же посчитать новую ось y, не получилось тоже

Comment: Вращение это несколько иное,чем простые вращательные движение в одноплоскостном формате поля.Я не знаю что такое опенджл,но скорее всего ваша сцена будет лишь менять ракурсы своей обозреваемости.

Comment: `glRotatef` нормально работает. Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа **подробно поясните**, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.